# How to get the resolution of screen (width and height) in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app for `Windows Phone 8.1` and my app just can work properly if I can get the resolution of mobile screen. I tried many ways but they just work on `Windows Phone 8.0` and lower. I tried these ways from:

1. [How to get screen size on Windows Phone 7 Series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596732/how-to-get-screen-size-on-windows-phone-7-series)
2. [How can I get a screen resolution of Device (Windows Phone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852416/how-can-i-get-a-screen-resolution-of-device-windows-phone)
3. [How to get Screen size of a windows phone 8 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298631/how-to-get-screen-size-of-a-windows-phone-8-device)
4. [How to get screen resolutions on Windows Phone devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304145/how-to-get-screen-resolutions-on-windows-phone-devices?rq=1)

If someone knows how to do it on `Windows Phone 8.1`, please help me!

If somebody can help me, I have a little question, I am using `Visual Studio RC2`, when I choose to develop an app for `Windows phone`, it is automatically tick OS version `8.1`, if i want to develop an app for OS version `8.0`, how to change that settings?
Edit: I solved the second question.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24142802/2681948)? As for WP8.1 versions - you should be aware that you can develop [WP8.1 Runtime (Store App) and WP8.1 Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn632732.aspx) - if you choose the second the VS will ask you if you want 8.1 or 8.0. Downgrade from 8.1 version to 8.0 is not possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Window.Current.Bounds to get the position and size of the available space your app can use on the screen.

```
Window.Current.Bounds
```